# Poker Ready Reckoner

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-strategy, poker-tools

This is a table with Card 1 along the top and Card 2 top to bottom  on the left. When you are dealt a particular hand, you can make notes in the appropriate box. Does anyone do this?

Comment: In most card rooms/casinos you can take notes. You cannot photograph or video tape the game. I know this is not an answer to your question, I'm not sure if players use Ready Reckoner in Poker.However doing it during a hand would be an excellent tell to all your opponents.

Comment: I agree with @RomanMik that it'd be a tell to your opponents. It also doesn't really give you much granularity in your note-taking, since your hole cards are but a single factor in how you might choose to play or think about a hand. So, IMO, it seems like a waste of time. Note-taking in general, though... that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I use my phone for taking notes as most people are used to seeing other players on their phones. It doesn't get other players suspicious about you taking notes. It just looks like you're distracted and texting. Most rooms do not allow you to use your phone at the table, so I just lean back after the hand is over and make my notes.

And kudos for taking notes, but you should probably just notate hands where you find something interesting or were confused about what you should do in a particular situation. Too much note taking and you will actually end up getting distracted.